# D3 Area-Chart energy example

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to learn d3js and started with an example of a Area Chart [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883195#index.html). I understand what is happening in this example and i tried to manipulate it a little bit to fix my data to this chart

my data looks like

```
date,close
0:15,0.433
0:30,0.919
0:45,0.750
1:00,0.699
1:15,0.629
1:30,0.896
1:45,0.794
2:00,0.802
2:15,0.866
2:30,0.943
2:45,0.750
3:00,0.518
3:15,0.721
3:30,0.649
3:45,0.816
4:00,0.698
4:15,0.403
4:30,0.772
4:45,0.605
5:00,0.721
5:15,0.684
5:30,0.559
5:45,0.697
6:00,0.751
```

and the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.area {
  fill: steelblue;
}

</style>

<body>
<div class="test"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width]);
    
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);
    
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");
    
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");
    
    var area = d3.svg.area()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y0(height)
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.close); });
    
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    d3.csv("data/data2.csv", function(error, data) {
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.close = +d.close;
      });
    
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
    
      svg.append("path")
          .data(data)
          .attr("class", "area")
          .attr("d", area);
    
      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);
    
      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("Price ($)");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this doesn't work and i think i know why...because now the x-axis is not a "date" and the domain isn't set in the right way?! So what do you think should i do? Is there a way to say d3 that the x-axis is a timestemp every 15 minutes?! And then, is the data set in the right way with ".data(data)" and not ".datum(data)".

best regards

linda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least 3 issues here:

1. You need to convert the time strings (eg `4:15`) to javascript `Date` objects when you parse the csv. `+d.close` is insufficient; use `d3.time.format('%H:%M').parse()` method for that.
2. For the `svg.append("path")` bit, calling `.data(data)` on it ends up just assigning the first element of `data` to the path, instead of the entire array. That's just the way d3 selections work with data. This in turn causes `.attr("d", area)` to only pass the single data point to the `area` generator, instead of the whole set. Instead of `.data(data)`, use `.datum(data)` (or, I think `.data([data])` would work as well), which will bind the entire array to the path.
3. As you point out, the scale `x` needs to be `d3.time.scale()`. However, fixing the 2 things above should already make it present the graph, but instead of having dates along the x axis, you would see relly big numbers, corresponding to milliseconds since 1970.

That should do it, unless there are other issues I missed. If so, put this stuff into a jsfiddle and I'll take a look.